# How to convert nested list strings to integers then sort them in python 3?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, nested-lists

Not an experienced programmer! Currently studying a computing GCSE in school and need help with a problem.

I have a nested list that holds the information of student names and then their score in a text file, this file then needs to be imported into a nested list. I have done this using the code -

```
scoresave = []
with open('class1quizscoreboard.txt') as scoreboard:
    for line in scoreboard:
        scoresave.append(line.strip().split(','))
print (scoresave)
```

And this works fine with the output of

```
[['Emily Scott', ' 7'], ['Student Name', ' 6'], ['Another Student', ' 2']]
```

This is what I expected, but how would I change the scores of the students into integers?

I have tried multiple solutions from this site that are similar but none have worked for me.

Comment: *"I have tried multiple solutions"* - could you share your closest attempt? *"none have worked for me"* - be more specific; provide error traceback, or inputs and expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sorted(map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], scoresave), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

to get what you want.

**Explanation:**

This converts your nested list's second element into ints.

`map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], scoresave)`

We pass that whole into these:

`sorted({}, key=lambda x: x[1])`

which sorts the list

Comment: @GeorgiaSteele `sorted(map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], scoresave), key=lambda x: x[0])` The only thing changed is the index `x[1]`->`x[0]`. Previously we are sorting by the second element (the integer x[1]). To sort alphabetically, sort the first element x[0]